# How to get google analytics accounts list and view list api?

Tags: node.js, api, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to write API for getting account list from google analytics.

So is it possible to call API only using API key?

How can I call analytics api?

Example showing in the websites isgiven below.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const blogger = google.blogger({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: 'YOUR API KEY'
});

const params = {
  blogId: '3213900'
};

blogger.blogs.get(params, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(`The blog url is ${res.data.url}`);
});
```

How to make call to analytics to pull the account list, views for each accounts, getting metrices etc.

Comment: welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: for startes i wouldnt use the blogger api i would use the analytics api.

Comment: Can I make API calls using API key? Is it necessary to get access token ?

Comment: Is there any way to get the all views and account that listed under our account?

Answer (score 2):

Your code currently uses the blogger api you need to be using the analytics api.

API keys are for public data only you need to be authorized to see user data.  The [account summery list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) method will allow you to see all of the accounts a user has access to.

```
var request = gapi.client.analytics.management.accountSummaries.list();
request.execute(handleResponse);
```

There are javascript samples on in the documentation it shouldnt be to hard for you to convert that and the documentation itself into working code for node.js

Comment: Thanks. Is it necessary pi with oauth2Client token?When calling with api key returns login required.

Comment: Can you please answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019714/why-google-analytics-query-response-total-user-count-varying-with-dimensions

Answer (score 1):

**Using a Service Account**

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const analyticsreportingv3 = google.analytics('v3');

// Inside function
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
keyFile: '<KEYLOCATION>',
scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    ],
});

// Acquire an auth client, and bind it to all future calls
const authClient = await auth.getClient();
google.options({auth: authClient});

// Do the magic
const accountlist = await analyticsreportingv3.management.accountSummaries.list({

});

console.log(accountlist.data);
```