# Why total users differ in Google analytics when using dimensions?

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

I tried analytics query using https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Issue happens when I'm adding dimensions in the query. I need to query data for some dimensions and need to save in my database.

Query 1

[image: Query 1]

Result 1
[image: Answer]

Query 2

[image: Query 2]

Answer 2

[image: Answer 2]

I am saving the second queried data to the database.

So when I need the total users for a particular date, here 2025-05-26, its 277 from Second query.

but the actual value showing 275 which is from query 1.

How can I handle this?

Comment: They are two different requests they are not going to match.  your inserting multi dimensional analytic cube data into a relation database.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the number of users is different in the 2 requests is normal.

The question is that there are actually 275 users for the selected period, however with the dimension of the medium the report is telling you that one from organic and once from cpc. Infact, the number of sessions is the same in both cases, but the users no so users cannot be added together.

Comment: Then how can I handle this? is there any need to query the same without dimensions to get the user count ?

Comment: With that metric you can't unless it also tracks the clientId and then groups the data after you export it to find the count. But to get the number it's better to use the first query.